# Get the image as file in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, html, image, typescript

I am making angular application with image upload option which has the,

**Html :**

```
<label class="hoverable" for="fileInput">
  <img [src]="url ? url : avatarImage"> 
  <div class="hover-text">Choose file</div>
  <div class="background"></div>
</label>
<br/>
<input id="fileInput" type='file' (change)="onSelectFile($event)">
<button *ngIf="url" (click)="delete()" >delete</button>


<img (click)="uploadPersonaImage($event)" class="avatar-images" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png">

<img (click)="uploadPersonaImage($event)" class="avatar-images" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar2.png">
```

Here what i am having is if the user clicks over the image he can select and update whatever image he has in local.

Same way if the user was not interested to update the profile image but interested to select any of the avatar image as per his/her wish which i have given like,

```
 <img (click)="uploadPersonaImage($event)" class="avatar-images" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png">

<img (click)="uploadPersonaImage($event)" class="avatar-images" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar2.png">
```

And in ts made something like this,

```
uploadPersonaImage(e) {
  this.url = e.target.src;
}
```

So on the click function the src that comes from the `event.target` was set to `this.url`..

But i need to convert it as file.. Because i need to send it as file to the service call so i need to update the avatar image.

So please help me to convert the avatar image selected/clicked by the user to the `file/formdata` so that it can be sent to the service as file format and can be updated as user selected image..

**Example:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-file-upload-preview-85v9bg

Comment: angular change event doesn't work on input type file

Comment: Unable to get you but I am not at all going to use input type file here (only to upload from local machine of user)..

Answer (score 2):

You can use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) to attach the read file and send to the API.

```
 onSelectFile(event) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {

      this.uploadToServer(event.target.files[0]);
      ... rest of the code
  }

  uploadToServer(file) {
    let formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('fileName', file);
    // call your api service to send it to server, send formData
  }
```

**EDIT**:

Try this out if you have no option to touch `onSelectFile()` or trigger a different function when you upload the file.

```
_url = ''
set url(val) {
  this._url = val;
  if (val) {
    this.dataURLtoFile(val);
  }
}

get url() {
    return this._url;
}
uploadedImage: File ;

dataURLtoFile(dataurl) {
    const arr = dataurl.split(',');
    const mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1];
    const imageExtension = mime.split('/')[1];
    const bstr = atob(arr[1]);
    let n = bstr.length;
    const u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);
    while (n--) {
        u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
    }
    this.uploadedImage = new File([u8arr], `uploaded.${imageExtension}`);
  }
```

On your API call, maybe when you click on a button,

```
uploadPersonaImage(e) {
  // this.apiService.someMethod(this.uploadedImage);
}
```

If you want to trigger the API call just when you upload the image, add the code of `dataURLtoFile()` to `uploadPersonaImage()` and call `uploadPersonaImage()` from `url` setter

**Clarification**

Do you understand what does `event.target.src` mean (considering `e` as event)?

1. Here `event` means the click/change event you triggered when you
   clicked onto upload photo.
2. `event.target` means the DOM element on which the event took place.
3. `event.target.src` will give you the `src` attribute value of the
   DOM element on which you triggered the change event.

Now, you say won't it work? No, it won't because the element which you clicked is an `HTMLInputElement` but the `src` resides under the image in under the `label` tag. And how are you intending to call `uploadPersonaImage()`? what calls your method? You haven't answered that even after asking so many times.

In my last edit, I have added code under the setter of the `url` which will convert the `dataUrlFile` to an actual File, It completely depends on your server how you want to store the file. As a file or as a dataUrl? If you want to send it as a file then follow the conversions I added in the answer if you want to save as dataUrl then directly save the content of `this.url` on your API call.

Comment: Can i have example from you?? Should i need to replace this ```uploadPersonaImage(e) {
  this.url = e.target.src;
}
``` with what you have given??

Comment: @HelloWorld yes, add the content of `uploadToServer()` under `uploadPersonaImage()`, call it from `onSelectFile` as I have called `uploadToServer()`

Comment: I am making it clear that i am not at all talking anything with ```onSelectFile(event)``` only thing is need help of how to convert the image in ```uploadPersonaImage(e)``` to file..

Comment: In ```uploadToServer(file)```, whether the (file) is the ```e.target.src```?? Please make some example i am getting confused..

Comment: @HelloWorld you don't need a File, all you need is convert to a BLOB, and send a FormData (as xyz did) to your server

Comment: @HelloWorld: It is `event.target.files[0]` as shown in the example, I am going out for a while, If it won't be clear to you, I will make an example later.

Comment: @xyz, I don't know whether i have explained clearly.. PLease don't touch the function```onSelectFile(event)``` nothing to do with ```event.target.files[0]``` and that function is working fine.. Only thing is please look out the function ```uploadPersonaImage(e)``` alone i need to make this only to file format and sent to service..

Comment: @HelloWorld So, Is there any way I can call `uploadPersonaImage()` ? Like in : `<input id="fileInput" type='file' (change)="onSelectFile($event); uploadPersonaImage($event)">`. **EDIT:** *There has to be a way to invoke the method when you upload the image, can I touch <input type='file' ...>?*

Comment: @xyz, Sorry dear no way i can use like that if so i might have tried with it.. But i should not.. Hope you understand my requirement, there will be some default images and user can select the needed and need to updated in service as file..

Comment: @HelloWorld: Why is your requirement like this? You can write a 1000 line of useful code but it won't work if you don't invoke it. You can have to find a place where you can trigger you API call after you upload the image, how do you intend to do that? **EDIT;** The "uploaded file" needs to be stored somewhere, the change event will be lost

Comment: I'm not sure if you guys are talking about the same things...I quickly implemented xyz solution : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-file-upload-preview-squj4f

Comment: @Florian: Yes right, this will serve the purpose. Store the file in a variable, use it when you call the API. Somehow OP is not clear about his requirement, in this case, he neither wants to touch `onSelectFile()` nor invoke a new function when `change` event fires

Comment: @xyz I think he can changes it, but he doesn't see the point. He would just like to transform his **image.src** to a blob>file and send it to his API when the button "send" is clicked. But I'm not sure that you can easily do that...

Comment: @Florian Yeah right, I edited my answer, probably now it is possible, thanks for the clarification

Comment: @HelloWorld Check the edit, does this solve your problem?

Comment: @xyz, I am still not understand your solution.. Is it not possible to convert the ```e.target.src``` (i still agree that i am having only source of the image) to formdata??

Comment: The ```onSelectFile``` function has everything what i need already so nothing to do with it and for clearance it is another separate functionality.. Whereas only thing i am getting the source in ```uploadPersonaImage``` is it possible to convert this source which is ```$event``` in ```uploadPersonaImage($event)``` to formdata ??

Comment: @HelloWorld: I have added some clarificarions in the answer, please go through it. I think I am done with this question and not going to followUp. if even the current solution doesn't work for you, your requirements don't suit me.